# How to make inline edit in admin order grid row?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid, inline-editor

Can any one please let me know how to override admin sales order grid ui component to make it inline edittable? I have added custom column in the sales order grid and want to make it edittable. Please explain with example.

There are multiple examples to making any custom grid inline editable. I need help for sales order grid.

Answer (score 0):

> **Add this type of code in your xml**

> my UI component file name : **inquiry_record_inquiry_list.xml**

> Datasource name is : **inquiry_record_inquiry_list_data_source**

> Column name is : **inquiry_records_columns**

> Route name : **productinquiry**

> Controller name : **productinquiry**

```
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
    <columns name="inquiry_records_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_record_inquiry_list.inquiry_record_inquiry_list.inquiry_records_columns.ids</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" path="productinquiry/productinquiry/inlineEdit" xsi:type="url"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_record_inquiry_list.inquiry_record_inquiry_list.inquiry_records_columns_editor</item>
                  <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                  <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                      <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                  </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="id">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        <column name="inquiry_status" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendore\ModuleName\Model\InquiryStatus</item>
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="align" xsi:type="string">center</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                   <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                  </item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       ......................................................
       ......................................................
       ......................................................
    </columns>
```

> **After Change Data save  using below file**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Productinquiry;

use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ProductinquiryFactory;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $jsonFactory;
    protected $_productinquiryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        ProductinquiryFactory $productinquiryFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->_productinquiryFactory = $productinquiryFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
            $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
            if (!count($postItems)) {
                $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
                $error = true;
            } else {
                foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $modelid) {
                    $model = $this->_productinquiryFactory->create()->load($modelid);
                    try {
                        $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$modelid]));
                        $model->save();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages[] = "[ID: {$modelid}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

> **For show Inquiry Status**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class InquiryStatus implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options['0'] = __('New');
        $options['1'] = __('Process');
        $options['2'] = __('Reject');
        $options['3'] = __('Complete');
        return $options;
    }
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You***